# Inserting a Page After Drawing a Shape

Tags: vba, ms-word

Using VBA, I can draw a circle and then insert a new page. However, the new page is inserted *before* the page with the circle on it (or the correct way to look at it might be: inserting the new page bumps the circle to the new page). How to I insert a new page so that it comes *after* the page with the circle on it?

Code demonstrating the problem:

```
Sub InsertShape()
  ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 154.8, 94.2, 189#, 129# _
      ).Select

  Selection.Collapse
  Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
End Sub
```

(In the simplistic example above, inserting the page break before drawing the circle achieves my goal. However, when the decision of whether to insert the new page needs to conditionally occur at some point after the circle has been drawn, moving insert page before drawing the circle isn't an acceptable solution.)

Thank you!

Comment: `Collapse` takes an argument which specifies which direction the collapse should occur.  Default collapses to the start, so try specifying the end. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171856(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: @TimWilliams, that worked. Thank you! Would you like to turn your comment into an answer so you can receive credit for answering this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collapse` takes an argument which specifies which direction the collapse should occur.

By default, if no argument is given, it collapses to the *start* of the selection/range, so try providing the specific direction you want:

```
Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171856(v=office.11).aspx